# Having trouble storing output of "wmic csproduct get vendor /format:list | findstr/c=" as a variable

Tags: batch-file, wmic

Thank you for checking out my question.
I am trying to:

- get the output of a wmic query into a variable

Here is some background information for why I need to get this accomplished.
The policy at my job requires that laptops and tablets equipped with webcams have them disabled in the BIOS.
Now that we are teleworking we have a need to enable the webcams in the BIOS.
We have tools that can be used to enable BIOS features while the system is running.
I want to write a script that will psexec into a machine, fetch the vendor information and store it in a variable that can be accessed later in the script once psexec exits.
I can write the rest of my script without issue I think, however I'm having trouble figuring out how to store the results of the following command in a variable:

```
wmic csproduct get vendor /format:list | findstr/c=
```

For example, the output of that command on my machine is:

```
Vendor=Dell Inc.
```

I want to capture the output and store it in a variable for later use in the script I'll be writing so that I can process vendor specific BIOS manipulation.
I have tried 
`set sysvend=wmic csproduct get vendor /format:list | findstr/c=`
But when I echo `%sysvend%` to see if it worked I get the following instead of what I wanted:
`wmic csproduct get vendor /format:list | findstr/c=`

If anyone knows how to do this I would greatly appreciate the help. I am open to other alternatives for determining the vendor.

Answer (score 4):

Even easier than using `find` or `findstr` and without the problematic `0x0D0D0A` line endings:

```batch-file
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions
For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%G In (
    '%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe CSProduct Get Vendor /Format:MOF 2^>NUL'
) Do Set "vendor=%%G"
```

*This solution also prevents unwanted trailing characters with the vendor name string, which can be a common occurrence.*

Answer (score 3):

There is a known `wmic` bug, so you need to parse `wmic` output using two nested loops, e.g. as follows:

```bat
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%s IN ('
    wmic csproduct get vendor /value ^| find "="
') DO for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ("%%t") do SET "vendor=%%i"
```

Here the `for` loops are

- `%%s` to retrieve the `vendor` value;
- `%%i` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned (`wmic` behaviour): each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` (CR+CR+LF) instead of common `0x0D0A` (CR+LF).

See Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call it a `wmic` bug, because it actually happens when using `for /F` to convert the Unicode output to ASCII/ANSI. Anyway, you don't need the `find "="` when you've got two `for /F` loops. The most general method is to use `"delims="` for the outer loop and `"tokens=1* delims=="` for the inner one, so you avoid trouble in case there are leading spaces in the value (although quite unlikely); but this would still lose leading `=`-signs (although even more unlikely)...

Answer (score 0):

Use `for %%i in (wmic csproduct get vendor /format:list ^| findstr/c=) do (set var=%%~I)`
What this does is that the for loop variable `%%i` becomes the output of the command in the for loop which allows you to set another variable the for loop variable. You need the caret (^) before the `|` in the for loop since if you didn't, the command would pipe out of the for loop and not execute in the for loop. You could also just surround the command with double quotes (`"`) and you wouldn't need to escape the pipe. As a result of the command,  `%var%` would become equal to the output of your wmic command.

The final command will be:

```bat
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims==" %%i in (' wmic csproduct get vendor /format:list ^| findstr /c:"=" ') do (set var=%%~i)
echo %var%
rem echoing var to make sure the variable is what you wanted
```

Output for me:

```
Vendor=Microsoft Corporation
```

If you want the output to be `Microsoft Corporation` specifically, you can add:

```bat
set var=%var:~7%
```

to remove the first 7 characters. You can also change tokens to `2*` instead of `*`. :

```
for /f "tokens=2* delims==" %%j in (' wmic csproduct get vendor /format:list ^| findstr /c:"=" ') do (set var=%%~j)
```

Outputs:

```
Microsoft Corporation
```

Notes:

In batch-files, unlike powershell, you cannot set a variable as a command and have it become the output which is why the conventional way to set output of a command to a variable is using the `for` loop. Also, just preference, I would suggest using the `/value` switch rather than `/format:list`.

**Tested and works for me**

Comment: With regards to not being able to set a variable as a command and have it become / generate the output, you are mistaken. Batch macro's can facilitate this, however it's more complicated and takes a higher level of understanding of batch scripting to construct such macro's. Additionally, the circumstances in which it's appropriate are somewhat Niche.

Comment: Sorry Neko, but your posted output is not possible from your posted solution. Your output would be `Vendor=Microsoft`. Your variable `%var%` will contain the following string, `Vendor=Microsoft`, and I'm sure that the OP would like it to contain, in this case `Microsoft Corporation`.

Comment: @Compo Why is it not possible? It worked for me, is there a certain setting on your computer that doesn't allow this to be possible? Or is it something or my computer?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the error, edited and works now

Comment: @NekoMusume, sorry, but that's still not correct. Your variable content will still be `Vendor=Microsoft Corporation`, you'd want to change `tokens=*` to `Tokens=1*` and then use `%%j` for your variable value instead of `%%i`.

Comment: Was the variable being `Vendor=Microsoft Corporation` not intended?

Comment: Well @NekoMusume, only the OP can answer that, but generally especially with a variable named using a known name, there'd be no need for the string value to also carry the `Vendor=` part.

Comment: I see, I will add your suggestion in another section as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214212/discussion-between-neko-musume-and-compo).

Comment: With regards your latest edit, @NekoMusume, I didn't suggest `2*`. Also using your example, if the vendor string included a `=` character, it wouldn't capture the entire string, just that up to the included `=`, everything else after the `=` would be assigned to `%%k`.

Comment: It worked for me and I don't think `*1` works for my for loop

Comment: "vendor" is 6 characters, = is 1

Comment: I didn't type or suggest `*1`, @NekoMusume, please read [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61898371/having-trouble-storing-output-of-wmic-csproduct-get-vendor-formatlist-finds#comment109483665_61898597) again!

Comment: @Compo I changed it so it doesn't say you suggested it . Try my exact code, `1*` tokens doesn't work

Comment: @NekoMusume, I don't believe that `for /f "tokens=2* delims==" %%j in (' wmic csproduct get vendor /format:list ^| findstr /c:"=" ') do (set var=%%~j)` works for you, but my suggestion with your variable now changed from `%%i` to `%%j`, `for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%j in (' wmic csproduct get vendor /format:list ^| findstr /c:"=" ') do (set var=%%~k)` doesn't initially define the variable with the same content, only without possibly removing any string value containing a `=` character and those which follow it..

Answer (score 0):

Answer posted to demonstrate the command can be assigned and executed as a variable, Contrary to Neko's answer, as per the OP's question.

```
@Echo Off
Set Get.Vendor=^>"%TEMP%\Vendor.log" (wmic csproduct get vendor /value ^| 
findstr /c:=) ^&^& (For /F "UsebackQ Tokens=2* Delims==^EOL" %%A In ("%TEMP%\Vendor.log") Do For /F "Delims=" %%T In ("%%A") Do Set "Vendor=%%~T") ^&^& Echo.!Vendor!
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
%Get.Vendor%
pause
```