# processing with cmd.exe for loop the output of command which contains a carriage return <CR>

Tags: batch-file, carriage-return

I'm trying to process the output of the command `wmic os get version` in a cmd.exe batch for loop. Seems simple enough:

```
for /f %%G in ('wmic os get version') do (
    echo %%G
)
```

But the output is:

```
Version
10.0.19044
ECHO is off.
```

That last line, `ECHO is off.` means that the `%%G` was "blank".

Ok so no problem, just test for that:

```
for /f %%G in ('wmic os get version') do (
    if [%%G] neq [] echo %%G
)
```

Output is the same:

```
Version
10.0.19044
ECHO is off.
```

So is it *not* blank? After much experimentation, it contains a single carriage return character aka `<CR>` aka 0x0D aka \r (not to be confused with line feed aka `<LF>` aka 0x0A aka \n; also note that `<CR><LF>` pair is the standard windows/dos line terminator), as this code demonstrates:

```
for /f %%G in ('wmic os get version') do (
    echo /////////%%G\123\
)
```

Output:

```
/////////Version\123\
/////////10.0.19044\123\
\123\////
```

So the question is, how to detect/process that last line with the carriage return. Can I detect it with an `if` comparator? Can I string substitute it? Can I use some `for` delimiter? What can I do? My immediate need is to just not print that last line for neatness, but one can imagine any arbitrary processing wanted on the text, including `for /f` with tokens and other delims.

Comment: Another method I like to use is the `format:csv` option. In other words, `for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%g in ('%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe os get version /Format:csv') do set "_version=%%g"
echo %_version%`

Answer (score 2):

The output of WMIC is unicode !

The trailing `<CR>` can be removed by passing the value through another `FOR /F` loop.

This also removes the phantom "blank" line (actually a `<CR>`)

```bat
@echo off
Title Removing the trailing ^<CR^> by passing the value through another FOR /F
set "Version="
@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"wmic os get version /Value"') do (
    @for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do if not defined Version set %%b
)
echo OS Version : [%Version%]
pause
```

---

***EDIT:*** Refer to this good answer here [wmic output to file without addtional line issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63153964/3080770) and [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61899766/3080770) from @Compo; You can also in your case change the output format of [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic): `/Format:MOF`

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Change the output of WMIC into MOF
@For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%A In ('"WMIC OS Get Version /Format:MOF"') Do Echo OS Version : [%%A]
pause
```